# $x$ is smaller than all positive numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have $0\le x \lt h$ for all $h \gt 0$. Prove that $x=0$. I know it is obvious but I can't prove it.

My try : I think it has some connections with concept of limit but I can't prove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Approach 1:**

Suppose that $x\ne 0$ then take $h=\frac{x}{2}$ and then

$$h<x$$

what is a contradiction.

**Approach 2:**

Another approach is use the sequence $h_n=\frac{1}{n}$, $0_n=0$ and use Squeeze Theorem:

$$0_n\le x<h_n$$

because $h_n\to 0$ and $0_n\to0$.

Comment: Very nice answer ! Can you provide a different answer without using contradiction method ?

Comment: You can even take $h=x$ and that'll still be a contradiction

Comment: @S.H.W: You can, for example, use a sequence $h_n=1/n$ and use the squeeza theorem

Comment: @Arnaldo,  could you please help me with this question :: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2228579/if-x-be-the-a-m-between-y-andz??

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x$ is an infinitesimally small positive number close to $0$, e.g., $x = 2^{-(2^{127} - 1)}$. Then $0 < x$. But now $x < h$ is now true only for *almost* all $h > 0$, but not *all* $h > 0$. So the condition $h > 0$ essentially pushes $x$ all the way down to $0$.